# Equalize column javascript not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm using this mootools javascript snippet to equalize the height of my columns:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() 
{
    var columns = $$('.equalize');
    var max_height = 0;

    columns.each(function(item) 
    { max_height = Math.max(max_height, item.getSize().y); });

    columns.setStyle('height', max_height);
});
```

Problem is it's not working properly on Chrome. It's getting the minimum height of the 2 columns instead of getting the maximum. What seems to be the problem and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to go on a different track - but why are you using JavaScript to do this? It *can* be accomplished with [CSS](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-3-column-holy-grail-pixels.htm), and even tables I feel are a better solution then doing it with JS.

Comment: `display: table[-row|-cell]` is a bit better solution.

Comment: @Crozin It certainly is, unless you require it work in IE6 / 7.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

`window.addEvent('load', function(){
});`

not the 'domready' event for this.

Some elements may not be loaded yet when the 'domready' event is fired.